# How to get raw text from pdf file using java

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox

I have some pdf files, Using pdfbox i have converted them into text and stored into text files, Now from the text files i want to remove

1. Hyperlinks
2. All special characters
3. Blank lines
4. headers footers of pdf files
5. “1)”,“2)”, “a)”, “bullets”, etc.

I want to get valid text line by line like this:

> We propose OntoGain, a method for ontology learning from multi-word concept terms extracted from plain text. OntoGain follows an ontology learning process dened by distinct processing layers. Building upon plain term extraction a con-cept hierarchy is formed by clustering the extracted concepts. The derived term taxonomy is then enriched with non-taxonomic relations. Several dierent state-of-the-art methods have been examined for implementing each layer. OntoGain is based upon multi-word term concepts, as multi-word or compound terms are vested with more solid and distinctive semantics than plain single word terms. We opted for a hierarchical clustering method and Formal Concept Analysis (FCA) algorithm for building the term taxonomy. Furthermore an association rule algorithm is applied for revealing non-taxonomic relations. A method which tries to carry out the most appropriate generalization level between a relation's concepts is also implemented. To show proof of concept, a system prototype is implemented. The OntoGain allows transformation of the derived ontology into OWL using Jena Semantic Web Frame-work1. OntoGain is applied on two separate data sources a medical and computer corpus and its results are compared with similar results obtained by Text2Onto, a state-of-the-art-ontology learning method. The analysis of 11.5 CCD1.1 results indicates that OntoGain performs better than Text2Onto in terms of precision extracts more correct concepts while being more selective extracts fewer but more reasonable concepts.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: use regex to do your needs

Comment: Furthermore: *All special characters* Which characters do you consider special? - *headers footers* How do you expect to recognize headers and footers after extraction? You had better not extract them to start with, i.e. using `PDFTextStripperByArea` - *1),2)a), bullets etc* **etc** is always a difficulty in specifications.

Comment: except dot it should to remove all special characters($#@!%^&*(){}"?/,<>), and it should remove text with hyperlinks

Answer (score 42):

Using [pdfbox](http://pdfbox.apache.org/) we can achive this

**Example :**

```
public static void main(String args[]) {

    PDFParser parser = null;
    PDDocument pdDoc = null;
    COSDocument cosDoc = null;
    PDFTextStripper pdfStripper;

    String parsedText;
    String fileName = "E:\\Files\\Small Files\\PDF\\JDBC.pdf";
    File file = new File(fileName);
    try {
        parser = new PDFParser(new FileInputStream(file));
        parser.parse();
        cosDoc = parser.getDocument();
        pdfStripper = new PDFTextStripper();
        pdDoc = new PDDocument(cosDoc);
        parsedText = pdfStripper.getText(pdDoc);
        System.out.println(parsedText.replaceAll("[^A-Za-z0-9. ]+", ""));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        try {
            if (cosDoc != null)
                cosDoc.close();
            if (pdDoc != null)
                pdDoc.close();
        } catch (Exception e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks but I have already tried this, but it is removing valid numbers and dots also, i need to convert this along with full stops(ending of sentence) and numbers with points(eg 11.3, ACD1.1) as mentioned in my stack

Comment: Then modify the regex based on your requirements.

Comment: Can u suggest me the regex because i never used regex earlier

Comment: parser = new PDFParser(new FileInputStream(file)); is given an error

Comment: you can use `\\p{L}\\p{N}\u0301-` (add punctuation what you need).
Source: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html

Comment: for those looking at this, the latest way to load document is `pdDoc = PDDocument.load(new File(fileName));
pdfStripper = new PDFTextStripper();`

Comment: For the newer versions: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58798622/894565

Answer (score 24):

**Hi we can extract the pdf files using [Apache Tika](http://tika.apache.org/)**

**The Example is :**

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.tika.metadata.Metadata;
import org.apache.tika.metadata.TikaCoreProperties;
import org.apache.tika.parser.AutoDetectParser;
import org.apache.tika.parser.ParseContext;
import org.apache.tika.sax.BodyContentHandler;

public class WebPagePdfExtractor {

    public Map<String, Object> processRecord(String url) {
        DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        try {
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpGet);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            InputStream input = null;
            if (entity != null) {
                try {
                    input = entity.getContent();
                    BodyContentHandler handler = new BodyContentHandler();
                    Metadata metadata = new Metadata();
                    AutoDetectParser parser = new AutoDetectParser();
                    ParseContext parseContext = new ParseContext();
                    parser.parse(input, handler, metadata, parseContext);
                    map.put("text", handler.toString().replaceAll("\n|\r|\t", " "));
                    map.put("title", metadata.get(TikaCoreProperties.TITLE));
                    map.put("pageCount", metadata.get("xmpTPg:NPages"));
                    map.put("status_code", response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() + "");
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                    if (input != null) {
                        try {
                            input.close();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception exception) {
            exception.printStackTrace();
        }
        return map;
    }

    public static void main(String arg[]) {
        WebPagePdfExtractor webPagePdfExtractor = new WebPagePdfExtractor();
        Map<String, Object> extractedMap = webPagePdfExtractor.processRecord("http://math.about.com/library/q20.pdf");
        System.out.println(extractedMap.get("text"));
    }

}
```

Comment: Just tried Tika, and I easily parsed pdfs, powerpoints, text files, excel, csv, etc, all with a few lines of code that worked for everything. A+ library, definitely recommend.

Comment: I would say its way better solution than the others answered

Comment: Note: Apache Tika's PDF capabilities are a thin wrapper around Apache pdfbox.

Answer (score 17):

You can use [iText](http://itextpdf.com/) for do such things

```
//iText imports

import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfReader;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.parser.PdfTextExtractor;
```

for example:

```
try {     
    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(INPUTFILE);
    int n = reader.getNumberOfPages(); 
    String str=PdfTextExtractor.getTextFromPage(reader, 2); //Extracting the content from a particular page.
    System.out.println(str);
    reader.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println(e);
}
```

another one

```
try {

    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader("c:/temp/test.pdf");
    System.out.println("This PDF has "+reader.getNumberOfPages()+" pages.");
    String page = PdfTextExtractor.getTextFromPage(reader, 2);
    System.out.println("Page Content:\n\n"+page+"\n\n");
    System.out.println("Is this document tampered: "+reader.isTampered());
    System.out.println("Is this document encrypted: "+reader.isEncrypted());
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

the above examples can only extract the text, but you need to do some more to remove hyperlinks, bullets, heading & numbers.

Comment: Thanks, what is itextpdf is it an alternative to pdfbox or after extracting text i need to use this, can u please provide me some examples on this?

Comment: From where we can download iText Lib Can you provide download link here?

Comment: @ShylendraMadda you can download it from here "http://itextpdf.com/product/itext"

Answer (score 11):

For the newer versions of [Apache pdfbox](https://pdfbox.apache.org/). Here is the example from the original [source](https://svn.apache.org/viewvc/pdfbox/trunk/examples/src/main/java/org/apache/pdfbox/examples/util/ExtractTextSimple.java?view=markup)

```
/*
 * Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
 * contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
 * this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
 * The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
 * (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
 * the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 */
package org.apache.pdfbox.examples.util;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.encryption.AccessPermission;
import org.apache.pdfbox.text.PDFTextStripper;

/**
 * This is a simple text extraction example to get started. For more advance usage, see the
 * ExtractTextByArea and the DrawPrintTextLocations examples in this subproject, as well as the
 * ExtractText tool in the tools subproject.
 *
 * @author Tilman Hausherr
 */
public class ExtractTextSimple
{
    private ExtractTextSimple()
    {
        // example class should not be instantiated
    }

    /**
     * This will print the documents text page by page.
     *
     * @param args The command line arguments.
     *
     * @throws IOException If there is an error parsing or extracting the document.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        if (args.length != 1)
        {
            usage();
        }

        try (PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(new File(args[0])))
        {
            AccessPermission ap = document.getCurrentAccessPermission();
            if (!ap.canExtractContent())
            {
                throw new IOException("You do not have permission to extract text");
            }

            PDFTextStripper stripper = new PDFTextStripper();

            // This example uses sorting, but in some cases it is more useful to switch it off,
            // e.g. in some files with columns where the PDF content stream respects the
            // column order.
            stripper.setSortByPosition(true);

            for (int p = 1; p <= document.getNumberOfPages(); ++p)
            {
                // Set the page interval to extract. If you don't, then all pages would be extracted.
                stripper.setStartPage(p);
                stripper.setEndPage(p);

                // let the magic happen
                String text = stripper.getText(document);

                // do some nice output with a header
                String pageStr = String.format("page %d:", p);
                System.out.println(pageStr);
                for (int i = 0; i < pageStr.length(); ++i)
                {
                    System.out.print("-");
                }
                System.out.println();
                System.out.println(text.trim());
                System.out.println();

                // If the extracted text is empty or gibberish, please try extracting text
                // with Adobe Reader first before asking for help. Also read the FAQ
                // on the website: 
                // https://pdfbox.apache.org/2.0/faq.html#text-extraction
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * This will print the usage for this document.
     */
    private static void usage()
    {
        System.err.println("Usage: java " + ExtractTextSimple.class.getName() + " <input-pdf>");
        System.exit(-1);
    }
}
```

Comment: it assumes pdf should be on disk, doesn't work with webpage pdf?

Answer (score 1):

Extracting all keywords from PDF(from a web page) file on your local machine or Base64 encoded string:

```
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument;
import org.apache.pdfbox.text.PDFTextStripper;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class WebPagePdfExtractor {

    public static void main(String arg[]) {
        WebPagePdfExtractor webPagePdfExtractor = new WebPagePdfExtractor();

        System.out.println("From file:   " + webPagePdfExtractor.processRecord(createByteArray()).get("text"));

        System.out.println("From string: " + webPagePdfExtractor.processRecord(getArrayFromBase64EncodedString()).get("text"));
    }

    public Map<String, Object> processRecord(byte[] byteArray) {
        Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
        try {
            PDFTextStripper stripper = new PDFTextStripper();
            stripper.setSortByPosition(false);
            stripper.setShouldSeparateByBeads(true);

            PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(byteArray);
            String text = stripper.getText(document);
            map.put("text", text.replaceAll("\n|\r|\t", " "));
        } catch (Exception exception) {
            exception.printStackTrace();
        }
        return map;
    }

    private static byte[] getArrayFromBase64EncodedString() {
        String encodedContent = "data:application/pdf;base64,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" +
                "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" +
                "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" +
                "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" +
                "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" +
                "DudB4Yf6YBZywk9cpBKRR5PAI8Dv16tHRY5wKf0mdWcE7zIZ+1UJSbyFPzllwqHssCjwL9yPSn0iCX9W7eznRxYyNAzIi5isTi3nHrhh4XsSj4FHnGZbpv5zl62XNIOpjv6TypmSvBi77W67swocgv4zUZO1I5YgcmCmUgCw2cgy4150U+Bm7TgKxCnGi1iVcmgTVIoR0mK4lonE5YSaaSD4bByMBx3Xc2Es8+iKniNmo7Nwpp1lO2dXa1CZbAGXXe0KsVCH1EDnir0B9iK61OhGO4a4Mr/46edy42OnxobYWG2F//72Czbz6bZDCnsKfY0O8DiYGfYPtd3Fnu6FYl8biBK28/LiMgd3QJqv4gabSpg/QWKGlmuh76uLI82xjzLGfMFTb3yxt89vdKws+oqJvo6euRePQ/8FrgeWMW6HthwfSiBnwIb+FtHb7xaap6902VxUhpOtNan23oWXVUElerOziV0QUPNvKfmiV4fl05/+aAXbZWde/7q0KXTJWN51GNFF/irmVsZOjPuseEfw3+GV8PvhT8M/y69LX0qfSWdlz6XLpMiXZ" +
                "AuSl9L30ofS1+4+rvNkHv2JDIXcyXyFtPVrbC315hYOSpvlx+W4/IO+VF51lUp8og8JafkXbBsd8/Nm2+lt3L05Siidftz51jiWdFcTzgD3/2YAM2L2DcD88hYo+PwaaLfYt4MOglt75PXqYiF2BRLb5nuaTHzXd/BRDAejJAS3B2cCU4FDwncfZaDu2CbwZrozQ3z4Sr6KuU2PyG+JxSr1U+aWrliK3vC4SeVCD59XEkb6uS4UtB1xTFZisktbjZ5cZLEd1PsI7qZc76Hvm1XPM5+hmj/X3j3fe9xxxpEKxbRyOMeN4Z35QPvEp17Qm2YzbY/8vm+I7JKe/c4976hKN5fP7daN/EeG3iLaPPNVuuf91utzQ/gf4Pogv4foJ98VQplbmRzdHJlYW0KZW5kb2JqCjEzIDAgb2JqCjEwNzkKZW5kb2JqCjggMCBvYmoKWyAvSUNDQmFzZWQgMTIgMCBSIF0KZW5kb2JqCjMgMCBvYmoKPDwgL1R5cGUgL1BhZ2VzIC9NZWRpYUJveCBbMCAwIDU5NSA4NDJdIC9Db3VudCAxIC9LaWR" +
                "zIFsgMiAwIFIgXSA+PgplbmRvYmoKMTQgMCBvYmoKPDwgL1R5cGUgL0NhdGFsb2cgL1BhZ2VzIDMgMCBSID4+CmVuZG9iago5IDAgb2JqCjw8IC9UeXBlIC9Gb250IC9TdWJ0eXBlIC9UcnVlVHlwZSAvQmFzZUZvbnQgL0NOVFpYVStNZW5" +
                "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" +
                "L0l0YWxpY0FuZ2xlIDAgL0FzY2VudCA5MjggL0Rlc2NlbnQgLTIzNiAvQ2FwSGVpZ2h0IDcyOQovU3RlbVYgOTkgL1hIZWlnaHQgNTQ3…/ZfICj5JcLdi/ATmQZKogDPg0lIDBunI0ZGOB1OB/Lpyce1TbJqCpBThycVs3GyQPZSLKexbMGyFss8LF4sNb2lElu5HPlJ2439G1jKsbRh6cTyPNpx8I6AFxa8P+xD2E4e/G+5PqJ/8aDzERFvGBJR/WLkfwcM3kRCiZpokDMdxhn5MeD9Rn5MSm0mYUpLSF98J5HXaQgtpJvoDWGesEe4C4NgK3woWsQ88RgzszXsMM4WyALeIC5gO5B/FYk/pNxVCJGoZT8NYc8LIknrONeVQYznus51pYeZHCaXw+RYIJLAEogJfMEbVPrvv31S6icvTMlp1EQhO41cOuXb0EEkSYkmGaMXSzuIfhCKAA4Y/YScTs9ASizblWVyWB1UT4fwNfSp9+mgwLFd4oI3D++9++kuheYWpOnEeBhLJrv7kVg" +
                "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" +
                "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" +
                "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" +
                "JTPMvxBMSaYoSmQ+nHtDywiJbzyzTe7xcfDmR5vTBcyPsKv7yBPEyXopGDxCAHOoUoppRILPQiribnP/IqOjlLka3XEo5eIbu8bCTCqRmej6+99ib/lF6im3/13ItnD8OtF4LyxN+YxQq0iwTyqjsx0mwIFVUkLkZSWbX1dmiLORxlVBGTIWSC" +
                "NNE0wTAxNnJCdIHTeHOcTzt1nM80dUbxARJ9r/0+T2BoAA0leOYPHXrlpnIwoYmg8NPdo9LFdJYupavSQ9JD09Xpmtzw3IjcyNyo3OjcmNzY3LhcWzVUi9WsWqpWVYdUh1arqzXecG+EN9Ib5Y32xnhjvXFem5POpPLJEh5Ff6LMf2vVqgwKOx" +
                "IeHbu64vXswkn3v54zdkzOzp2Oubnjy6B7dMEZfqlnubDymyWVX/SsEFbeWCy3YknJ0NxCWddt/CFxKspCjmFZ7tgfY1ibvokegcNxGL9GKZGsUI5imYqJoV/8GMZcsm0pXJhNRtkbfuofdPmBA3IYu/rV+/Oa6I3VNatqa1fVrF7Xc1xSe4um" +
                "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" +
                "uIAowMDAwMDAzNzk2IDAwMDAwIG4gCjAwMDAwMDg2ODcgMDAwMDAgbiAKMDAwMDAwODcwOCAwMDAwMCBuIAowMDAwMDA4NzI3IDAwMDAwIG4gCjAwMDAwMDg3ODAgMDAwMDAgbiAKMDAwMDAwODc5OSAwMDAwMCBuIAowMDAwMDA4ODE4IDAwMDAwIG4gCjAwMDAwMDg4NDUgMDAwMDAgbiAKMDAwMDAwODg4NyAwMDAwMCBuIAowMDAwMDA4OTA2IDAwMDAwIG4gCnRyYWlsZXIKPDwgL1NpemUgMjYgL1Jvb3QgMTQgMCBSIC9JbmZvIDEgMCBSIC9JRCBbIDxkYjc4M2NhNDM2Mzg4YzI5ZDc5MDQ2NzY3NjUxNjE3OT4KPGRiNzgzY2E0MzYzODhjMjlkNzkwNDY3Njc2NTE2MTc5PiBdID4+CnN0YXJ0eHJlZgo5MTA0CiUlRU9GCg==";
        String content = encodedContent.substring("data:application/pdf;base64," .length());
        return Base64.decodeBase64(content);
    }

    public static byte[] createByteArray() {
        String pathToBinaryData = "/bla-bla/src/main/resources/small.pdf";

        File file = new File(pathToBinaryData);
        if (!file.exists()) {
            System.out.println(" could not be found in folder " + pathToBinaryData);
            return null;
        }

        FileInputStream fin = null;
        try {
            fin = new FileInputStream(file);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        byte fileContent[] = new byte[(int) file.length()];

        try {
            fin.read(fileContent);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return fileContent;
    }
}
```