# How to convert a pdf file that has data columns to a database that can be accessed using java

Tags: java, pdf

I am thinking of how to convert a large pdf file with lots of data in it to a database which can be used by my java application. That pdf file contains numbers as well as character data, like names related with numbers displayed as a column.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to try to divide your problem into steps and search after a suitable solutions on google.

You can start here -

[How to get raw text from pdf file using java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18098400/how-to-get-raw-text-from-pdf-file-using-java)